# ERROR - VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation

Tags: react-native

I'm working on a **react-native** app and I have to put a list of object in a **Scrollview**, so I use the **FlatList** component to do it. This is the piece of code that generates the error:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={style}>
   Other components
   <FlatList
       style={style}
       data={data}
       scrollEnabled={false}
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
       renderItem={({ item, index}) => (somethings)}
   />
   Other components
</ScrollView>
```

The complete error is: **VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can break windowing and other functionality - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.**

Comment: Sometimes it deactivates the touch, it is not considerable only warning

Comment: You can disable this warning so, it will not deactivate the touch, you will not face this in production.

Comment: Disabling the warning is not a solution

Comment: I have posted the answer actually, the reason behind it using the nested scroll views like flatlist inside scrollview.

Comment: @Tebo the article u attached wasn't work

Answer (score 42):

Avoid using FlatList with the same orientation. Instead, restructure your code like this --

```
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={style}>
    Other components
    {
      data.map((item)=> <Somthing item={item}/>)
    }
    Other components
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. This is the simplest.

Comment: the most straight forward answer, simplest in all senses

Comment: This answer is ok if you have a very small list to render but larger  list will give you performance and memory issues

Comment: I take the error on macos. I used like this and solved my problem.                                 <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

            <Text style={styles.title}>
                Products
            </Text>
            {
                DATA.map((item)=> <Item title={item.title} price={item.price} />)
            }
        </SafeAreaView>

Answer (score 26):

Flatlist has its own ScrollView you can scroll through the list using that so there is no need to put a flatlist into a ScrollView that is why its giving a warning, the both scrollview will clash and one of them (mostly the parent one) works.

Comment: The code does not foresee this, I need an external structure that is scrollable and inside other components including a list of objects that I represent with a FlatList with scrollEnabled={false}

Answer (score 26):

**Solution:**
I have also encountered same problem with `FlatList`. Then the package below solved my problem.

**'react-native-virtualized-view'**

```
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-virtualized-view'
```

Comment: It is not a proper solution you cant not use it in animated view

Comment: Not working in my case

Answer (score 23):

The error is self explanatory and it should be in a developers best interest to avoid these kind of things even when it's just a false alarm.
Your particular situation could use the following solution:

```
<FlatList
  data={data}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => `key-${index}`}
  ListHeaderComponent={() => (
    <SomeComponents>
      ...Some components those need to be on top of the list
    </SomeComponents>
  )}
  ListFooterComponent={() => (
    <SomeComponents>
      ...Some components those need to be below the list
    </SomeComponents>
  )}
  renderItem={({ item, index}) => (somethings)}
/>
```

Another note, if you need more complex list that needs header and footer for the list itself, you can try [`SectionList`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist).

Comment: worked as expected thanks!!

Comment: what if we have 2 flatlist inside scrollview?

Comment: @Alfi, you should not have 2 flatlists inside a scrollview. It's faulty business logic, one should wonder what the UX (i.e. scrolling) would be like. Consider using the `.map()` function if you have a potentially smaller number of items in the data source.

Comment: @rule_it_subir For example, look at Twitter or Instagram's user profile. How do they achieve that without nesting FlatLists inside of a ScrollView? After tinkering for quite a while, it seems the only way to achieve this layout is to render a navigator of FlatLists inside of a ScrollView, but would love to hear if there is better way to do this.

Comment: adding 2 flatlists inside a scrollview is faulty business logic? sometimes you have to put multiple scrollviews inside main scrollview. I'm new to react-native. but in flutter you can easily put any number of scrollviews inside a scrollview if you wrap them with sizebox widgets(which gives them constant width and height)

Answer (score 21):

Your component `FlatList` and `ScrollView` have the same orientation(vertical), so you need put your component inside a `ScrollView` with horizontal orientation like this:

```html
<View>
    <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true} style={{ width: "100%" }} >
    <View>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <FlatList />
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: This would get rid of the error, but it might not be a good solution if the desired orientation of both lists IS vertical - thus is more of an anti-pattern than a proper solution

Answer (score 16):

**Solution 1:** Use `FlatList` props `ListHeaderComponent` and create all of your page top section in that. Something like this: [image]

This will not show any warning or error.

**Solution 2:**
Because only parent view will scroll (`ScrollView`) and not the child `FlatList`, so to get rid of the warning you can pass a prop **scrollEnabled={false}** to the `FlatList`.

If it doesn't go then **import LogBox from react-native** and write this in your component

```
useEffect(() => {
  LogBox.ignoreLogs(["VirtualizedLists should never be nested"])
}, [])
```

hopefully, the warning will be removed.

Comment: Still has the error

Comment: I've updated my comment, please try now @Jim

Comment: This is not solving the Problem but only surpressing the Errormessage. The message comes for a reason, you should try to solve it instead of supressing it.

Comment: @Stophface This is not a problem this is just a warning, maybe in the next version of react-native, they add the check if the child FlatList has a prop of scrollEnabled={false} then don't show the warning.

Comment: Its an error, not a warning. It can have sideeffect (they are mentioned in the error message) when surpressing this.

Answer (score 11):

Anyone want to solve this issue can use a custom `VirtualizedScrollView` like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';

const VirtualizedScrollView = props => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      {...props}
      data={[]}
      keyExtractor={(e, i) => 'dom' + i.toString()}
      ListEmptyComponent={null}
      renderItem={null}
      ListHeaderComponent={() => (
        <>{props.children}</>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default VirtualizedScrollView;
```

Then if you use `FlatList` inside `VirtualizedScrollView`, it won't get the warning/error.

```
<VirtualizedScrollView>
  <FlatList 
    /*--- your props ---*/
  />
</VirtualizedScrollView>
```

There is a npm package where I get this code, you can also use this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-virtualized-view)

Answer (score 8):

If you need put a FlatList expanded inside a scrollview, you need disable scroll from FlatList and expand it with `flex: 1`.
To disable scroll you cold add the code below

```
<FlatList
nestedScrollEnabled={true}
scrollEnabled={false}
data={[1,2,3,4]}
renderItem={({item}) => {
    return <CardItemPurchasedList/>
}}
```

Comment: tnx..
nestedScrollEnabled={true}
scrollEnabled={false}

Answer (score 8):

> [When false, the view cannot be scrolled via touch interaction.](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollenabled)

```js
<ScrollView>
    <ListView 
        scrollEnabled={false} />
</ScrollView>
```

I solved this issue by setting `scrollEnabled={false}` in internal `VirtualizedLists` as it will not make it scrollable via touch interactions. By default, it has `scrollEnabled={true}`, which leads to two scrollable List in the same orientation. But if you have two different orientations of them then there's not catch!

Comment: Thanks Worked, Chatgpt needs to learn more from stackoverflow :).

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatList` like this  `ListHeaderComponent` and `ListFooterComponent`:

```js
<FlatList ListHeaderComponent={
    <ScrollView
        style={styles.yourstyle}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    >
        <View style={styles.yourstyle}>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
    }
    data={this.state.images}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        return (
            <View
                style={styles.yourstyle}
            >
                <Image
                    source={{
                        uri: item,
                    }}
                    style={styles.yourstyle}
                    resizeMode={"contain"}
                />
                <Text
                    numberOfLines={2}
                    ellipsizeMode="tail"
                    style={styles.yourstyle}
                >
                    {item.name}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }}
    keyExtractor={({ name }, index) => index.toString()}
    ListFooterComponent={
        <View style={styles.yourstyle}></View>
    }
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The react-native FlatList component have some advantages over just mapping over an array and render out the ItemComponent. The FlatList optimizes the rendering process and only renders the elements in view. So for longer lists you should always use the FlatList component for performance reasons. If you have a list inside a ScrollView you can just pass the property `scrollEnabled={false}` to the FlatList. That ensures the scrolling of the ScrollView is working fine and the warning doesn't pop up.

```js
<ScrollView>
  <SomeContentComponent />
  <FlatList
   {...props}
   scrollEnabled={false}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the 2 vertical ones(I'm assuming their side by side, separated with a segemented control?) by using the same flat list and switching out the data when it's switched. If they're just two vertical flat list's one after another use the SectionList.

For the horizontal one you can try putting the Horizontal FlatList in the ListHeaderComponent of the vertical FlatList and see what happens. It can be janky if you use a vertical FlatList in a vertical scroll view but maybe with two different axis it might be ok. The other option is two only show a few items in the horizontal scrollview and have a "Show More".

The last option is too re design/rethink the page so it's not doing so much. On mobile less is more and developers/designers like to get in the mindset of porting desktop thinking onto mobile. Might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `SectionList` approach to solve this & wanted to post a code example because I found the [`Section` data required by React Native to be clear but also quite prescriptive](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist#requiredsections).

```
 renderList = ({empty, posts}: {empty: boolean, posts: Array<Object>}) => (
    <SectionList
      sections={[
        {type: 'MAP', data: [{}]}, // Static sections.
        {type: 'PROFILE', data: [{}]},
        {type: 'POSTS', data: posts} // Dynamic section data replaces the FlatList.
      ]}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      renderItem={({item, section}) => {
        switch (section.type) {
          // Different components for each section type.
          case 'MAP':
            return <MapView />;
          case 'PROFILE':
            return <Profile />;
          case 'POSTS':
            return <Post item={item} />;
          default:
            return null;
        }
      }}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Separator />}
      ListFooterComponent={() => <>{empty && <EmptyList />}</>}
    />
  );
```

What's nice is that the content feels logically quite separate, so you can add sections easily or have different dynamic data sources.

(If you're building a form & want better keyboard handling, you could also try a `KeyboardAwareSectionList` from `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`.)

Answer (score 0):

**Error ?** you are trying to render a FlatList component inside a scrollview component, this is what is throwing  the warning.

**solution**  Render the components using  Flatlist's ListHeaderComponent={} prop, i.e in your flatlist add the prop as follows

```
const FlatList_Header = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{
            height: 45,
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "#00B8D4",
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
                    }}
        >
 
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, color: 'white' }}> Sample FlatList Header </Text>
 
        </View>
    );
  }
<FlatList
    data={BirdsName}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <ItemRender name={item.name} />}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={ItemDivider}
    **ListHeaderComponent={FlatList_Header}**
    ListHeaderComponentStyle={{ borderBottomColor: 'red', borderBottomWidth: 2 }}
      />
```

Note the use of the **ListHeaderComponent** in the code above, that should supress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

if ScrollView is Vertical change Flatlist Horizontal

```
<ScrollView >
<FlatList
   horizontal
   data={lenders}
   keyExtractor={(_, index) => index}
   renderItem={(item) => {
            return <Text>item</Text>
      }}
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was happening due to nesting of `ScrollView`.

Try replacing some of the `ScrollView` from children components with `React.Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Iam Useing React Native to Develop Mobile Application, i am useing scrollview inside Flatlist getting error. Flatlist has it's own Scollview Functionality so there is  no need to put Flatlist into a ScroolView Component. so u can remove ScrollView Component when u are useing Fllatlist Component [image]

Answer (score -1):

By Default Flatlist horizontal property is set to true.
Update this horizontal={false} property in flatlist.

It'll throw the same error if you are trying to render items horizontal with  numColumns={2} property.

To use numColumns property set horizontal={false}